# Error when importing Sceneform Asset for obj and gltf file

Tags: android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I get this error while importing Sceneform Asset: Gradle build failed with new import rules. Would you like to revert the changes? and the options are Revert and Keepbroken gradle changes.

A error messege also pops up:

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.RecipeExecutor.append(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;)V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem with Android studio 3.6, I reverted to 3.5.1 and the import worked fine. With 3.6 I got the exact same problem and crash.

Seems to me as there are more people having this problem:

https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/912

Comment: Importing manually appears to work also - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60515952/334402 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450919/334402