# Import .obj in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, arcore

I'm developing an application with AR in Android Studio and I want to import an .obj file.
For older versions of android studio people used Google Scenefrom Tool but in the version 4.1 is not available.
Does anyone know of an equivalent plugin for this version or any way to import the .obj?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want not only import the .obj but you want to convert it to .sfa and .sfb?

As you probably know, the sceneform library is deprecated ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453399/google-sceneform-is-it-deprecated-any-replacement)). There are different ways to go from here:

1. If you still want to use the sceneform library, you could use [this](https://github.com/thomasgorisse/sceneform-android-sdk) repository.
2. If you are not bound to sceneform, you could have a look [here](https://github.com/zirman/arcore-filament-example-app). This is a example app demonstrating the combination of Filament and ArCore.

I am afraid, the usage of sceneform will stay very difficult, the only way would be to use an older version of android studio ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468709/gradle-build-failed-with-new-import-rules/60515952#60515952)).