# Sceneform 1.15 Unable to play fbx animations in ARCore- Android

Tags: android, arcore, gltf, fbx, sceneform

I'm new to Sceneform (1.15.0) and related 3D file formats like fbx and glTF. I saw the sample animation project [(Andy Dance)](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/v1.15.0/samples/animation) on how to run animations and the [sceneform](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/animation/enable-animations) documentation.

**What am I trying?**

Run animations that are present in the sceneform fbx assets. I have 2 assets- a [ka27 helicopter](https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/1560653) and a [3d model](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2wmPdoprlRlLVd2Y1RxUUxYYmM)

Both these fbx assets have some animation. When I try to import these assets into Android Studio, it currently throws an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413649/error-while-importing-fbx-with-import-sceneform-asset-in-android-studio-3-6) which I've overcome by adding the sceneform asset into my `sampledata` directory and adding the information in the `app/gradle` file. The .sfa and .sfb files are generated correctly.

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/ka27.FBX',
        'default',
        'sampledata/models/ka27.sfa',
        'src/main/res/raw/ka27')
```

[image: The generated .sfb file]

But now if I try running the animation, I can see the helicopter in the scene, but without animation-

```
arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(helicopterNode);
AnimationData animationData = helicopterRenderable.getAnimationData("ka27");
ModelAnimator helicopterAnimator = new ModelAnimator(animationData, helicopterRenderable);
helicopterAnimator.start();
```

**My Questions-**

1. Are these assets correct and compatible with sceneform animations?
2. In `getAnimationData`, what is the parameter that needs to be passed? Can i find this information by opening this asset? 
   (I tried importing these assets, including sceneform's sample `andy_dance` into `Blender` and `Unity` and while I can see the animation playing, I really can't see `animation data` name property anywhere.)
3. Do `.fbx` to `.glTF` converted assets retain their animation?
4. Can sceneform run `.glTF` animations?
5. Do animations have to be exported separately for sceneform? If yes, then how?

Sample illustration of the app in which the `.fbx` animation does not work-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you open your `.sfa`, you will find a key `animations` if your `.fbx` file contains any animation. It should look like this:

```
{
  animations: [
    {
      clips: [
        {
          name: 'Animation 001',
          runtime_name: 'animation_1',
        },
      ],
      path: 'sampledata/models/ka27.fbx',
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

`getAnimationData` expects the value of `runtime_name` so you need to modifiy the following line:

```java
AnimationData animationData = helicopterRenderable.getAnimationData("ka27");
```

With my `.sfa` file this line becomes:

```java
AnimationData animationData = helicopterRenderable.getAnimationData("animation_1");
```

You can notice that `getAnimationData` can also take as parameter the index of the animation in the array `animations` of the `.sfa` file. So you can write:

```java
AnimationData animationData = helicopterRenderable.getAnimationData(0);
```

The documentation of the `ModelRenderable` is available [here](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ModelRenderable?hl=en#getAnimationData(java.lang.String)).