# Sceneform 1.15.0 .sfa and .sfb files not getting generated

Tags: android, kotlin, sceneform

I am using `Android Studio version 4.0` and to get started with `Sceneform 1.15.0` i firstly added all the dependencies and plugins mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/import-assets) .
Inside my `sampledata` folder in the `app` folder i have added both `.obj` and `.mtl` files for the model. Now when i click `import sceneform asset` i don't see any `.sfa` or `.sfb` file generated in any of my project folders. Though `Sceneform 1.18.0` is available at the moment but I am using `Sceneform 1.15.0` since support for `.sfa` and`.sfb` was removed in `Sceneform 1.16.0` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk#choosing-the-right-sceneform-sdk-version-for-your-project).
How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you download the plugin of sceneform from within android studio ?

Comment: yes i had already downloaded  the Google Sceneform tools plugin

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it manually.

[Error while importing FBX with Import Sceneform Asset in Android Studio 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413649/error-while-importing-fbx-with-import-sceneform-asset-in-android-studio-3-6)
I had the same issue and was able to fix it using this.

Have a look at the answer with the 4 steps. After the gradle sync finishes don't forget to rebuild the project.

Comment: ok so i wasn't rebuilding the project so i do have the .sfa and .sfb files generated now as mentioned in that 4-step method but on opening the sfb file i get the error as "File was loaded with wrong encoding 'UTF-8' "

Comment: I get the same UTF - 8 error, let me know if you figure it out?

Comment: Also Mehul since we are both new to AR and are facing issues would you mind sharing your email id so that we can help each other? I completely understand if you wish not to share it.

Comment: Aryan i would definitely have no problem in that but even though my device is android 9 and google play services for android require android 7+, my device still shows not supported and my laptop isn't powerful enough for an emulator with 4GB of RAM . For now i'm no longer working on AR so i don't think it will be helpful even if i drop my email here. But good luck to you for making great AR apps in the future !