# 3D model file in Android ARCore do not render texture and color

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, fbx

I took a 3D model in fbx type in into Android Studio. When I run the android app, the model shows but lose its color. This is the look of source:
[image]

And this is the effect in app:

[image]

The model lose its color and texture.

It's a common question when took the fbx file into Android Studio. The source models had their texture and color , even in other 3D inspector. But they don't show texture in Android Studio And the app running.

below is the import code in build.gradle:

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/plants.fbx',
    'default',
    'sampledata/models/plants.sfa',
    'src/main/res/raw/plants')
```

All the codes are from the Google Demo Project hellosceneform just as below:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
    .setSource(this, R.raw.plants)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Toast toast =
              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
          return null;
        });
```

How can I do to make the texture of 3D model work. I tried other models, but all the fbx file lose their texture when running in Android app. In addition, the large size file failed to import in Android Studio and report 'Error creating sfa'.

Anyone had the experiences in ARCore development and Please help.

Comment: No experience, but do you have all of your material dependencies (textures, etc.) in the correct place: https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/import-assets#import_a_3d_asset. Also realize that Sceneform SDK for Android 1.15.0 is no longer supported.

Comment: **Try this, I solved by this method** https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450919/15721032